# GetTimeZoneInformation function returns struct with "incorrect" values

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

I have an issue with calling the function `GetTimeZoneInformation` on a certain machine.

Specifically, my machine is set to **EST/EDT** *(auto adjust for DST is disabled)* and after a call to the function my `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct has an identical **StandardName** & **DaylightName** *(Eastern Standard Time)*, and the **StandardBias** and **DaylightBias** are both Zero(0) and the return value is Zero(0).

On another machine *(with the same EST/EDT zone and disabled auto adjust)*, the `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct shows a **StandardName** of **Eastern Standard Time**, but the **DaylightName** is set to **Eastern Daylight Time**, and the **DaylightBias** is equal to -60, and the return value is 0.

Both machines are Windows 7 64bit OS.

I've checked the registry where the auto dst adjust setting is stored and both machines have the same value.

Is this possibly a side effect of a group policy setting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Both have the same updates?  Updates often include new information about timezone information/rules.

Comment: The updates are controlled by IT. i.e. It's all automated. I don't see any huge gulf between what's on my laptop (working) and the other machine (not working). I contacted them and they gave some b.s. answer having to do with time server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue, I've discovered a fix. *Open up Date and Time dialog*. Press the *Change time zone...* button.

Choose a Time zone that doesn't observe Daylight Saving Time. e.g. Hawaii. Press Ok for the *Time Zone Settings* dialog, then OK for the *Date and Time* dialog.

Open the *Date and Time* dialog again, open the Time Zone Settings dialog again and select your original time zone (you'll notice at this point that the auto adjust checkbox is checked for all zones that observe DST).

You can uncheck the *Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time* checkbox.

Press OK for *Time Zone Settings*. Press OK for *Date and Time*.

After these steps a call to `GetTimeZoneInformation` will assgin the `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct DaylightName member with the string, in my case, "Eastern Standard Time", and the DaylightBias value of 0.

Cheers.

Comment: You'll have to check that last sentence, it says that nothing got fixed.

Comment: Wrong. Prior to the steps I've outlined the DaylightName was "Eastern Daylight Time" with a DalightBias of -60.